# How to calulate the percentage of textbox1 & textbox2 in textbox3 till two places of decimal?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have three textbox textbox1, textbox2, textbox3

where

Textbox1.Text = 739 

TextBox2.Text = 2.95 

TextBox3.Text = Val(TextBox1.Text) * Val(TextBox2.Text) / 100

I want to calulate the percentage of textbox1 & textbox2 in textbox3 ...

But remember the value in textbox3 will appear till two places of decimal..i.e xx.xx, 233.xx, 3333.xx etc....

where .xx is the two places of decimal .... I want it in vb.net, asp.net (vb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you parse it as a double, it will be precise enough to calculate:

```
TextBox3.Text = (Double.Parse(TextBox1.Text) / Double.Parse(TextBox2.Text) * 100.0).ToString("#0.00")
```

Notice I wrote it as `100.0` to force it to be a `Double`.
And at the end, I convert it to a string, formatting it to two decimal points.

Comment: But it calculate the wrong percentage ... : the right answer is :


TextBox3.Text = (Val(TextBox1.Text) * Val(TextBox2.Text) / 100).ToString("#0.00")

Comment: @user512392; yes, I changed it. It wasn't clear in the question that 2.95 is the percentage of 739 that you're trying to calculate.

Comment: @BeemerGuy sir, your calculate is something wrong ,   its should be `TextBox3.Text = (Double.Parse(TextBox1.Text) * Double.Parse(TextBox2.Text) /100.0).ToString("#0.00")  `